# What's another word for a square?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Cambridge Dictionary says [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/square#:%7E:text=a%20boring%20person%20who%20does%20not%20like%20new%20and%20exciting%20ideas%3A) of *square* is old-fashioned:

> a boring person who does not like new and exciting ideas.

Then, what's another non-old-fashioned word or phrase for it?

---

Postscript: I might have found a synonym for 'square' now- it's 'puritan'. Not sure if this word is common enough, though. *Cambridge Dictionary* gives the following definition.

> someone who believes that it is important to work hard and control yourself, and that pleasure is wrong or unnecessary

Background of my question: In [a comedy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz4JWfYSgL8&ab_channel=animemaglife), a middle schooler from heaven is sent to earth to learn about human. But living on her own, she instead indulges herself in video games so much that she skips classes and never cleans her room. When she knows that her elder sister is visiting, she shivers in scare. She explains that her sister is a **sqaure**, serious and strict, so she is fearful of the outcome of her degenerate life being found out.

Comment: Are you looking for something formal or polite, or a slang term, and if it's slang, what kind of slang (where from, etc)? And how rude or offensive do you want it to be?

Comment: @StuartF Isn't there any that's suitable for both formal and informal? I don't want it to be rude.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I'm talking about showing little interest in things welcomed by the new generation.

Comment: @Michael -  Ahh!  How about *close[d]-minded* -- not open new ideas or opinions.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther Sounds better.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I prefer a word for someone who won't be called 'cool' by 'cool kids'.

Comment: @Michael - If that's the word you're looking for you should update your question because your question says you're looking for someone who does not like new ideas.  Voting to close.

Comment: Did you do any research? A thesaurus (searching for synonyms of "square") would be an obvious place to start.

Comment: @Michael party-pooper, curmudgeon, killjoy, buzzkill, spoilsport.

Comment: @Brandin: these mean "square"? Not quite.

Answer (score 3):

From a couple of web sources, synonyms of *square* (noun) in this sense:

[Merriam-Webster *square* synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/square)
**stuffed shirt, fuddy-duddy** et al.

[Word Hippo *square* synonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/square.html)
**conservative, conventional, conformist** et al.

Comment: *stuffed shirt* and *fuddy-duddy* are also both fairly old-fashioned.

Comment: I'm quite fond of "stick-in-the-mud". Is it old-fashioned? I don't know, but most people will probably understand what you mean and it seems less risky than some other alternatives.